# How to enable the thumbnail of gimp brushes on nautilus

Tags: 14.04, gimp

I've recently install a box with ubuntu gnome 14.04 and I've noted that the gimp brushes don't have a thumbnail. The xcf is ok with a gnome app for that, but for the .gih and .gbr I don't find yet an answer.